# Clicking a hyperlink in Excel to set autofilter on a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets, basically a one-to-many setup between the two sheets.   The first sheet lists several hundred companies and the second sheet lists the board of directors of the companies.   The second sheet has an auto filter so users can see board members for a specific company selected from the filter.

What I am attempting to do is have a user click the cell of the company on the first sheet so the user is then taken to the next sheet with the auto filter already populated with the company selected.  That way the user has direct access to the Board Members only for the company selected.

I imagine this would require VBA and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction for creating this code to solve this.    Many thanks.

Comment: Yep. VBA is needed here. See `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event, then tell the users that double-clicking on a cell will perform the action. If you want more **specific** help, you'll need to post the code you are building and where it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this by doing something this in the worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    'Update Table14 to your table name
    'Update Field to column number of the field you are filtering
    'Update Sheet7 to reference the sheet containing your table
    'Change on to the column number where your click should cause this action
    If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
    Sheet7.ListObjects("Table14").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
    'Update Sheet7 to reference the sheet containing your table
    Sheet7.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I see how this works.   I changed things around a bit to include a link in the column just to the right of the company name column.   I imagine the Criteria1: item would need to reference the active cell just to the left now.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it will need to reference the cell that has the name you want to pass. If you want to select the cell to the left of what is getting click you can use activecell.offset(0,-1).value

Comment: Last question.   If I want to limit the click actions to a specific table column in my Companies sheet, how would I go about that?

Comment: I've added an if statement to the sub to check the column number. Just change the 1 to the column you need and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to open the visual basic editor, right click the company worksheet,
view code, paste this in:

```
Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim CompanyName As String

        If Selection.Count = 1 Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1").EntireColumn) Is Nothing Then
                'This code is triggered when any
                'ONE cell in column C is selected
                'Simply change "C1" to "B1" etc etc


                'This MsgBox returns the selected cell
                MsgBox Target.Address

                'You'll probably need to collect some information
                'in this section. You can then use this to affect
                'the filters on sheet 2.
                'Perhaps like this
                CompanyName = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
                MsgBox CompanyName

                'This changes to "Sheet2"
                Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Hope that helps and you can make something of it