# Double-click on one Excel sheet filters another sheet to that value

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried to follow this link:
[Clicking a hyperlink in Excel to set autofilter on a different sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231790/clicking-a-hyperlink-in-excel-to-set-autofilter-on-a-different-sheet)
And this other follow up to it:
[Autofilter a table in another sheet based on selected cell value where autofilter needs to be 'contains'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397777/autofilter-a-table-in-another-sheet-based-on-selected-cell-value-where-autofilte?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I'm newer and more lost than these others.
I have 2 sheets. Accounts (Sheet1). One row per account (no duplicates). CustomerNames (Sheet2) may have multiple rows/names per account.

What I want to do is click on the Account Name (F2 = column header) in Sheet1, have it read the cell before it (column E) which has a number (since names may not be identical on my sheet2)

Then sheet 2 has a bunch of customer names at the account. I want this table to filter to the account number that corresponds to what was double clicked on sheet1 column E. On sheet 2 the matching data to sheet1 column E is in column D.

My headers are in row 2 and my tables are set to start with row 2 on both sheets.

I can't even get the double clicking to do anything. It doesn't even seem like my macro tries to run. I don't know that it would help to paste what I've tried. I just tried editing the other VBA I found on the links I mentioned.

Do I need to do something to set up the double click part?

My code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = 6 Then
        Sheet2.ListObjects("CustomerNames").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
        Sheet2.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain why the `If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = 6 Then`? That doesn't seem to match your question description.

Comment: I really have no clue what I'm doing and reading something else it seemed like I needed to offset the data to look at....basically, the people using this will click on the account name b/c the # means nothing to them and will be hidden but the numbers on each sheet are what match and if I was doing a vlookup these numbers would be the connection...

Comment: So, for clarification, the `=6` doesn't have any significance?

Comment: Well I thought it was the reference to the column that the account name in sheet 1 is in (column F) where people will click.

Comment: Setting up the double-click part, which is your actual question. In which **code module** is the code in the question? Have you set up a procedure to activate events? You need to research in the VBA Help how to work with events.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, try something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = 6 Then
        Sheet2.ListObjects("CustomerNames").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Target.Offset(,-1).Value
        Sheet2.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And to add it in I just right click on sheet 1, view code, paste it in? do i have to do anything to then run it?

Comment: Double click in column F to run it :)

Comment: I'm making progress. Now at least I'm getting an error when I double click: Run-time error '9':

Comment: That means you don't have a table named "CustomerNames" on Sheet2.

Comment: Is it b/c column 6 in sheet 1 a name (column 5 has the #) and then column 4 in sheet 2 is a #?

Comment: No. Type the following in the Immediate Window: `? Sheet2.ListObjects(1).Name` and press `Enter`. What is the result?

Comment: Ha ha! It works (file didn't save with my table names so it was an easy fix once I checked the table names). Thanks for helping a total newbie idiot!

Comment: Glad to help! Not an idiot, just a newbie :) Don't knock yourself, using events is pretty good for a newbie.